# How to create a macro in VBA that can automatically determine the boundaries of a matrix

Tags: vba, excel, matrix

I've started programing in VBA yesterday, and as such I am still quite the newbie at it.

I've tried to make a macro that automatically defines certain areas for me, and while it works quite well in my sheet, it is still limited in the sense that all sheets I use it on have to be identical in setup.

I am currently defining 5 areas

- A_mål - Single Cell
- Tank_Tabel - Matrix
- Int_Tabel - Matrix
- Bund - Single Cell
- HF - Single Cell

The optimal macro for my problem would be one that prompts the user to enter a number of a container, and then uses that number to automatically determine what sheet the information of said container can be found on, and the automatically determine where the listed areas are, and define them with the given names and the number that the user has entered.

The code can be seen here:

```
Option Compare Text
Sub Definer()
    Dim TankNr As Integer, rHF As Range, rAM As Range, rBV As Range, rTT As Range, rIT As Range

    If MsgBox("Vil du definere nye områder for en tank", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbYes Then

        TankNr = Application.InputBox("Indtast tank nr på den tank du vil definere områder for", "Tank Nummer", Type:=1)
        If TankNr <> 0 Then

            Set rHF = Sheets("Tank " & TankNr).Cells.Find(What:="HØJESTE FYLDEGRÆNSE =", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not rHF Is Nothing Then
                rHF.Offset(, 3).Name = "HF_" & TankNr
            End If

            Set rTT = Sheets("Tank " & TankNr).Cells.Find(What:="Enhed i tabellen : Liter", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not rTT Is Nothing Then
                rTT.CurrentRegion.Offset(2, 0).Resize(rTT.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 2).Name = "Tabel_tank" & TankNr
            End If

            Set rIT = Sheets("Tank " & TankNr).Cells.Find(What:="Interpolationstabel", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not rIT Is Nothing Then
                rIT.Resize(11, 11).Offset(1, 0).Name = "Int_tank" & TankNr
            End If

            Set rBV = Sheets("Tank " & TankNr).Cells.Find(What:="Bundvolumen =", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not rBV Is Nothing Then
                rBV.Offset(, 2).Name = "Bund" & TankNr
            End If

            Set rAM = Sheets("Tank " & TankNr).Cells.Find(What:="A-MÅL =", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not rAM Is Nothing Then
                rAM.Offset(, 1).Name = "A_mål" & TankNr
            End If

            MsgBox "Områder er blevet defineret"

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

There are several problems with this:

1. <strike>If the user enters a non integer in the input box, the code ends up with an error, rather than just ending the macro.</strike> **Solved**
2. <strike>If the user hits cancel in the input box, the code also ends up with an error rather than ending the macro.</strike> **Solved**
3. <strike>I tried to use the input "TankNr" as a reference, but it doesn't return the value of the cell, [but just what I've written as the reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVlFi.png)</strike> **Solved**
4. <strike>Finally, the current boundaries of each defined area is determined by me manually, and it works fine if the values I am looking for **is** actually in those specific cells. Sometimes the setup of the sheets might vary, and as such I need the macro to be able to automatically determine where the boundaries of the defined areas should be</strike>  **Solved**

The sheets in question can be seen [image: here]

Due to my reputation, I can only include these two links, but if there's a way to provide more documentation of my work, tell me and I'll happily do so.

Comment: Please can you post your code here rather than a picture?

Comment: I'd love to, but I'm not sure how to. It's my first question. Where can I add it? **Found it, code is now added**

Comment: If you use `application.inputbox` method you can specify a type of input - check vba help for details. So you could specify type=1 which is a number. For 3 you need to add =, e.g. `RefersToR1C1:="=Ark"` etc.

Comment: Wonderful, that's two problems solved, thank you very much

Comment: I don't think I understand 4 - how are the boundaries determined?

Comment: I've added a picture of Sheet1 and Sheet2. The defined areas in sheet1 should be A-mål = C10, HF = D13, Bundvolumen = K8, Tank_Tabel = B19:L32 and Int_Tabel = B37:L47. I've added that to the code manually, but that doesn't work for Sheet2 as the position of the needed areas is different. I don't know how to, but I need some clever way to make the macro determine where the correct cells are, but I don't know if that is even possible. One easier solution would be to make sure that all sheets are identical, but I'm not in charge of making the sheets.

Comment: You need to explain the basis for determining these areas. If there is identifying text then you could use the Find method to find these and define your areas.

Comment: There should always be the same text around the areas at least. The tables will always have cm, and the individual cells will always have the name of what is in that cell directly to the left of them. I haven't gotten it to work yet, but I think the answer below has at least some of what I am looking for. I'm sorry for not being clear about my needs.

Comment: @SJR I've added a sample code to the end of the question of what the solution could look like, but there's a problem with that code somewhere. It doesn't return any values at all. I tried testing with both a textbox and defining an area from the result, but it just turns out blank. Am I using the for each wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the approach I would use. It's only an example, for HF, but hopefully you get the idea and can extend to the other ranges. I've assumed the named range is the cell to the right of the one containing "HF".

```
Sub OptimalSolution()

Dim TankNr As Integer, rHF As Range

If MsgBox("Do you wish to define new areas for a container?", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbYes Then
    TankNr = Application.InputBox("Please enter the container number", "Container Number", , , , , , 1)
    Set rHF = Sheets("Ark" & TankNr).Cells.Find(What:="HF", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not rHF Is Nothing Then
        rHF.Offset(, 1).Name = "HF_" & TankNr
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant, you're a lifesaver. For the Tanktabel and Interpolationstabel, I'm thinking of just looking for the name the same way, but how do I define an area larger than one cell? Does .Current.Region do that for me?

Comment: Use `Resize`. E.g. `range("a1").resize(2,2)` is equivalent to `range("a1:b2")`. Does that help? The possible problem with `currentregion` is that it will include all contiguous cells so may include the text as well.

Comment: It looks like resize requires me to know beforehand how large i want the table to be? If that's the case then I can't use that option sadly. There will never be more than one instance of Tanktabel or Interpolationstabel in the sheet, there will only be numbers or blank spaces inside the table, and there will always be at least one blank space around the table.

Comment: If it's the table headed "TANKTABEL" then perhaps you can use `currentregion` and then resize by removing the first row if necessary.

Comment: I will try it out. Thank you very much for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if my understanding is correct. You may iterate a loop through starting range of Sheet 2, to get the addresses.
For example, if the labels like "A_Mål", "HF","Bundvolumen" will remain same in Sheet 2, you may use:

```
Sub GetRanges()
Dim A2, HF2, BV2, TT2, IT
For Each c In Range("A1:Z100")
' A1:Z100 is Random range, which might contain the ranges required
    If c.Value = "A_Mål" Then
    ' Check if this cell value matches A_Mål
        A2 = c.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Address
        ' Use Offset to take the one cell to right of matching cell
    ElseIf c.Value = "HF" Then
    ' Check if this cell value matches HF
        HF2 = c.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Address
        ' Use Offset to take the one cell to right of matching cell
    ElseIf c.Value = "Bundvolumen" Then
    ' Check if this cell value matches Bundvolumen
        BV2 = c.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Address
        ' Use Offset to take the one cell to right of matching cell
    ElseIf c.Value = "CM" Then
    ' Check if this cell value matches HF
        TT2 = c.CurrentRegion.Address
        ' Use CurrentRegion to take the current continous data of matching cell
    ElseIf c.Value = "INTERPOLCATIONSTABEL" Then
    ' Check if this cell value matches INTERPOLCATIONSTABEL
        IT2 = c.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).CurrentRegion.Address
        ' Use Offset to take the one cell to right of matching cell
        ' Use CurrentRegion to take the current continous data of matching cell
    End If
End Sub
```

Note: These variables gives you addresses of ranges in string data type
If you want actual ranges, simply remove ".address" from each line wherever mentions it.

Note2: A checked, label "Bundvolumen" has changed to "Volume" in Sheet 2.
The macro given above wont work in such cases.
But if you know the exhaustive list of names, which can be used to refer, it can be included with "OR" conditions in "IF" statements. Such as:

```
ElseIf c.Value = "Bundvolumen" or c.Value = "Volume" Then
```

Comment: This looks very promising, I will try to work it into the code and then return

Comment: I've tried to rework the code to my document, but it seems there's something wrong. While there's no error, it doesnt return a value of any sort. I've added the current code to the bottom of the post.

Comment: You may use msgbox, breakpoints or immediate window to check if any variable actually has a expected value or not. My favorite is msgbox. Like, before first 'ElseIf', you may use 'MsgBox A2' to check which value this variable holds.

Comment: I must acknowledge that, rather than looping through each cell in a range, Find method described by SJR will be a lot faster!

Comment: I got it to work using the find method, and everything runs smoothly now. I'll update the code in the original question. Thank you very much for your suggestion too. I'd upvote if I could, but I dont have reputation to do so

Comment: Hahaha! No need!